# Dealing with boilerplate in Haskell

Tags: haskell, boilerplate, duplication

This is kind of a soft question, but in the following code, there's a lot of duplication in the section marked "caesar ciphers." What's the "Haskell" way to deal with this? Should I make a higher order function? I thought about that, but I don't know what makes sense. Is there a "cipher" type that I could define for making ciphers?

Also, I know it may appear a little bit overengineered, in the sense that I'm doing the same error checking in two places, but I think it makes sense from the perspective of what each of the functions "means." Suggestions?

```
import Data.Char
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import Math.NumberTheory.Powers

--Helpers

extendedGcd::Integer->Integer->(Integer, Integer)
extendedGcd a b | r == 0 = (0, 1)
                | otherwise = (y, x - (y * d))
                where
                    (d, r) = a `divMod` b
                    (x, y) = extendedGcd b r

modularInverse::Integer->Integer->Maybe Integer
modularInverse n b | relativelyPrime n b = Just . fst $ extGcd n b
                   | otherwise = Nothing
                   where
                        extGcd = extendedGcd

relativelyPrime::Integer->Integer->Bool
relativelyPrime m n = gcd m n == 1 

textToDigits::String->[Integer]
textToDigits = map (\x->toInteger (ord x - 97)) 

digitsToText::[Integer]->String
digitsToText = map (\x->chr (fromIntegral x + 97)) 

--Caesar Ciphers

caesarEncipher::Integer->Integer->Integer->Maybe Integer
caesarEncipher r s p | relativelyPrime r 26 = Just $ mod (r * p + s) 26
                     | otherwise = Nothing

caesarDecipher::Integer->Integer->Integer->Maybe Integer
caesarDecipher r s c | relativelyPrime r 26 = mod <$> ((*) <$> q <*> pure (c - s)) <*> pure 26
                     | otherwise = Nothing
    where
        q = modularInverse r 26

caesarEncipherString::Integer->Integer->String->Maybe String
caesarEncipherString r s p | relativelyPrime r 26 = fmap digitsToText $ mapM (caesarEncipher r s) plaintext
                           | otherwise = Nothing
    where
        plaintext = textToDigits p

caesarDecipherString::Integer->Integer->String->Maybe String
caesarDecipherString r s c | relativelyPrime r 26 = fmap digitsToText $ mapM (caesarDecipher r s) ciphertext
                           | otherwise = Nothing
    where
        ciphertext = textToDigits c

bruteForceCaesarDecipher::String->[Maybe String]
bruteForceCaesarDecipher c = caesarDecipherString <$> [0..25] <*> [0..25] <*> pure c
```

Comment: Side note: The caesar stuff should probably go into its own module.

Comment: Another side note: `Math.NumberTheory.GCD.extendedGCD`, `Math.NumberTheory.Moduli.invertMod`.

Comment: Another side note: That number theory library is in a package on hackage called [arithmoi](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi).

Comment: Also, you can make this an instance of the [StreamCipher](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/crypto-api/0.9/doc/html/Crypto-Classes.html#t:StreamCipher) class from crypto-api.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Make a `Key` type, and use smart constructors

The main source of boilerplate seems to be the repeated checks that `r` is invertible, and calculation of its inverse. It makes sense to split your operations (eg `encipher`) into two steps: first *check*, then *actually encipher*. This way, you can write the checking part just once.

One way to achieve this is by defining a new type `CaesarKey` which is guaranteed to contain *only* valid keys. We can guarantee this invariant using [smart constructors](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Smart_constructors), as follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-} -- for the Key{..} syntax below

-- invariant: r and q are inverses mod 26. 
-- To ensure this invariant, we only export the 'caesarKey' smart constructor,
-- and not the underlying 'Key' constructor
data CaesarKey = Key { r :: Integer, s :: Integer, q :: Integer }

caesarKey :: Integer -> Integer -> Maybe CaesarKey
caesarKey r s = Key r s <$> invertMod r 26

-- ciphers
encipher :: CaesarKey -> Integer -> Integer
encipher Key{..} p = mod (r * p + s) 26

decipher :: CaesarKey -> Integer -> Integer
decipher Key{..} c = mod (q * (c - s)) 26

encipherString :: CaesarKey -> String -> String
encipherString key = digitsToText . map (encipher key) . textToDigits

decipherString :: CaesarKey -> String -> String
decipherString key = digitsToText . map (decipher key) . textToDigits
```

### Define `invert` on keys

Now we may take advantage of Daniel's observation that `decipher` is just `encipher`, but defined on a different key (namely the "inverse key"). So let's define an operation for inverting keys:

```
-- turns a key suitable for encoding into one suitable for decoding, and vice versa.
--   @invert (invert key) = key@
invert :: CaesarKey -> CaesarKey
invert (Key r s q) = Key q ((26-q)*s) r
```

and now we could throw out the `decipher` and `decipherString` functions as they are unnecessary (i.e. it's preferable to use `invert` instead).

### Make an `allKeys` function

Conceptually, we can split up `bruteForceCaesarDecipher` into two tasks: first, generate all possible keys; second, decode the text with each key. Let's implement this in code:

```
allKeys :: [CaesarKey]
allKeys = catMaybes $ caesarKey <$> [1,3..25] <*> [1,3..25]

bruteForceCaesar :: String -> [String]
bruteForceCaesar str = [encipherString key str | key <- allKeys]
```

Besides giving easier-to-understand code (in my opinion), splitting the code up in this way has the advantage that we only build the list of keys *once*, rather than having to rebuild the keys for every string we want to decode.

Note also a few other small changes:

- I used [`catMaybes :: [Maybe a] -> [a]`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Maybe.html#v%3acatMaybes) to throw out the `Nothing` keys
- I followed Daniel's suggestions for how to make `bruteForceCaesar` more efficient.

The complete code is [here](http://hpaste.org/66344).

Comment: I went through and followed your suggestions. This produced miraculously concise, readable code and avoided a lot of the gymnastics I was doing with <&>, fmap and family. Quick thing, in the allKeys declaration, the second list should actually be [1..25] as s does not need to be coprime to 26. Thanks a bunch, that really helped!

Answer (score 9):

Note that enciphering and deciphering use exactly the same algorithm, so you should have one function performing that.

```
transform :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
transform mult trans n = (mult * n + trans) `mod` 26
```

Then it is wasteful to check for coprimality and calculate the modular inverse for each character, thus I suggest

```
caesarEncipherString r s p
    | gcd r 26 == 1 = Just $ digitsToText $ map (transform r s) $ textToDigits p
    | otherwise     = Nothing

caesarDecipherString r s c = do
    mi <- modularInverse r 26
    caesarEncipherString mi (mi*(26-s)) c
```

For the brute force,

```
bruteForceCaesarDecipher c = caesarEncipherString <$> [1, 3 .. 25] <*> [0 .. 25] <*> pure c
```

since enciphering by all possible keys is the same as deciphering, just in a different order and less work; and it's too obvious that even numbers aren't coprime to 26.